# array destructuring using another array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following users array:

```
const usersArray = [ 'A', 'B'];
```

it could be any length:

```
const usersArray = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
```

i am extracting the first two using these variable names: userA and userB. These variable names are known.

```
const [ userA, userB] = usersArray;
```

Then i have some unknown user names that i get inside other users array:

```
const otherUsers = [ 'userC', 'userD', 'userE'];
```

how can I extract the values from `usersArray` under the variable names inside `otherUsers`? given that i first need to extract the known ones, then other ones.

### update:

I can do an unshift for the first two known variables:

```
otherUsers.unshift('userA', 'userB')
```

so now all my variables are inside `otherUsers`.
how can I extract them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

just use the rest property:

```
 const [ userA, userB, ...otherUsers] = usersArray;
```

Or alternatively use `slice` :

```
 const [ userA, userB] = usersArray;
 const otherUsers = usersArray.slice(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do is use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

```
const usersArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

const otherUsers = ['userC', 'userD', 'userE'];

const allUsers = otherUsers.unshift('userA', 'userB')

let joined = allUsers.join(',');

eval(`let [${joined}] = usersArray`);
```

now if you run `console.log(userA, userB, userC, userD, userE)`, you would get the defined variables.

N.B. because eval in not a [good way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!) to evaluate a string of code, you can use [window.Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). Just replace the eval call with the Function call like this:

```
Function(`let [${joined}] = usersArray`)
```